# Is it possible to query corporate news with Office Graph API?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, office365

I am currently working on a webpart in SharePoint, where I need to be able to query Corporate News on ACTOR(ME), but when I do that I get nothing back from my get request.

Is it possible to query with corporate news, or is the Office Graph API limited to just documents?
Right now my get request looks like this:

`'/_api/search/query?Querytext=%27ContentTypeId:0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900E1A7B5EB4F6D4536ABA24236F66055A100170370F5340444D1B84CA664EC7FB117*%27&rowlimit=3&selectproperties=%27Title,%20HitHighlightedSummary,%20Username,%20Path,%20ViewsRecent,%20EdgeTime,%20%20ViewsLifeTime,%20Weight,%20LastModifiedTime,%20PublishingRollupImageOWSIMGE%27'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Is it possible to query with corporate news, or is the Office Graph API limited to just documents?

No, it is limited to documents. *The [Office Graph](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/develop-office-graph) computes insights across Office 365 and makes these insights available through the Microsoft Graph, the single endpoint that you can use to access a number of Microsoft's cloud technologies. See [Microsoft Graph](https://graph.microsoft.io/).
Currently there are two insights from the Office Graph that you can query for: TrendingAround and WorkingWith.*

And if you want the Office Graph API to support this feature, you can submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: Thank you very much! Then I don't need to spend more time trying to get it to work, when it is not even possible :) Guess I will just sort the corporate news from some variable instead